# Uploading File from C Client to PHP Server

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I got a C client which needs to upload a file to web server.
I am opening the file and sending it using Windows libraries.

On the server side I would like to write a PHP script that save the file.

**Question #1:**
Since this is not the usual HTML FORM POST to PHP - how do I transfer the **filename** along with it's data?
Using POST '/upload.php?file=filename' and sending the data in the body is recommended?
If i use this, i can grab the filename via $_GET and file content via $_POST.

**Question #2:**
What happens if file spans more than 1 packet? I need to track the connection somehow on the PHP side to append the POST body to the file. Is there any clean way to do it?

Thank You!

Comment: **one** question at a time please ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You should try [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se), it can do file upload too.

Alternatively, you can learn about multipart/form-data mime type and how it encodes files and metadata. In short, you split the request body in parts with a boundary, and add headers to each file.

Comment: I cannot use libcurl in my project.
I am using WinHTTP (reading the entire file and posting it to a php script_

Comment: Oh. Well then, if can use multipart/form-data format (and it should), the file should be found in the $_FILES array in PHP, as it is when it is sent by a browser. If it really just sends the file as a whole request body, well, too bad, use GET.

Comment: And before you ask, I believe you will need to read a "file" called 'php://input' to receive that data in the second case. And I'm not sure it is not held in RAM before you do that (since PHP usually parses POST data and populates the $_POST array before actually starting the script).